# Why my script taking more time using data.table compared to data.frame (example given)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I am simply calculating max of timestamp group by a few columns and my data size is 50 GB , I tried both data.frame and data.table , but using data.table (42 mins) is taking more time than that of using data.frame (24 mins) . Ideally , data.table should be faster (by 10-20x time saving) . Can anybody tell me where I am making mistakes in my script ?  It is a simple script so I did not create any example because it's just about my script optimization

### Using Data.Frame

```
Sys.time()
"2020-01-11 16:46:25 GMT"

df <- mydata_0 %>% 
  group_by(customer, location_id, report_date, hour) %>% 
  slice(which.max(created_time))

Sys.time()
"2020-01-11 17:10:20 GMT"
```

### Using Data.Table

```
Sys.time()
"2020 - 01 - 11 17:36:43 GMT"

DT_df <- DT_mydata_0[, created_time == max(created_time),
                     by = .(customer, location_id, report_date, hour)]

Sys.time()
"2020 - 01 - 11 18:17"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to use the similar code as in `dplyr`, use the `which.max`, get the row index with `.I`, extract (`$V1`) and use that to  subset the data

```
i1 <- DT_mydata_0[, .I[which.max(created_time)],
        by=.(customer,location_id,report_date,hour)]$V1
DT_df2 <- DT_mydata_0[i1]
```

---

Or another option is `setkey`

```
setkey(DT_mydata_0, c('customer', 'location_id', 'report_date', 'hour', 'created_tiime'))
i1 <- DT_mydata_0[, .I[1], .(customer,location_id,report_date,hour)]$V1
DT_mydata_0[i1]
```

Comment: @Cole : Initially ,I was using filter(x==max(x)) in dyplr initially , then I used which.max(x) to get faster results ...

Comment: What is V1 here ?

Comment: @YogeshKumar  Is this getting faster

Comment: @akrun : There seems to be an error while executing your script..                                Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                       by=.(customer,location_id,report_date,hour)]$V1
                 ​DT_df2"

Comment: @YogeshKumar  Sorry a `]` was not closed.  Can you try now

Comment: @akrun : Yes , it worked like charm & very fast (less than 50 seconds !)  and thanks a lot . Can you pls share any link for learning advance query using data.table ?

Comment: @YogeshKumar  I would suggest to  fiirst go through the vignettes in data.table